# Get a stamp date from a scanned image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract the date from the following image.

[image]

I tried using `tesseractocr` library but I couldn't go any further....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add specific code

Comment: I don't think its possible. The image is too small and rough.

Comment: @Nouman what about this? [link](https://i.imgur.com/R55aWNM.png)

Comment: Whats the difference? You just increased its width and height. The image is still not clear.

Comment: If your image is crystal clear then you can use `selenium` and [this site](http://www.to-text.net/) to get text.

Comment: unfortunately this is the image actual size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtually impossible, the resolution and image quality are insufficient.

You can try by computing the normalized correlation map with ten trained digits of the same size (for a fully automated solution you will have to estimate that size :-( ) and keep the local maxima that have a good score.

You will get too many maxima and you will have to find the best non-overlapping candidates. Nothing really easy.